# Export RDS snapshot to s3 Using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

I want to export RDS snapshot to s3 using cloudformation which will trigger lambda function. But i'm kind of new to this. Can someone please help me out. I've already written the script for Lambda and SNS but i'm confused that how can I do export RDS snapshot to S3 using cloudformation. I'm attaching my file of Triggering Lambda from SNS. Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

````
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: >
  example-lambda-sns
  Example CloudFormation template to subscribe a lambda to an SNS Topic.
Resources:
  ExampleTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName: !Sub 'example-sns-topic'
      TopicName: !Sub 'example-sns-topic'
      Subscription:
        - Protocol: lambda
          Endpoint: !GetAtt ExampleFunction.Arn
  
  ExampleFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: mylambdafunction
      Description: mylambdafunction
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Role: arn:aws:iam::48
      CodeUri: 's3://testing/tes.zip'

  ExampleFunctionInvokePermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref ExampleFunction
      Principal: sns.amazonaws.com   

  ExampleTopicPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy'
    Properties:
      Topics:
        - !Ref ExampleTopic
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'sns:Publish'
            Resource: !Ref ExampleTopic
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
            Condition:
              ArnLike:
                AWS:SourceArn: !Sub 'arn:aws:*:*:${AWS::AccountId}:*'```
````

Comment: Do you want to export the snapshot _while applying the CloudFormation template_ or do you want to use CloudFormation to create a system where a message posted to SNS triggers a Lambda that performs the snapshot?

Comment: @Parsifal  I want to make a CloudFormation template  where a message posted to SNS triggers a Lambda that performs the snapshot

Answer (score 1):

following is sample example for lambda function. which will get trigger from sns. SNS will receive notification when snapshot is created.

```
import json
import boto3
import uuid
import datetime
import os
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snapshotarn = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    snapshotarn=snapshotarn.split()
    snapshotarn=snapshotarn[10].replace('.','')
    print(snapshotarn)
    rds=boto3.client('rds')
    export=rds.start_export_task(
        ExportTaskIdentifier='export'+'-'+uuid.uuid4().hex,
        SourceArn=snapshotarn,
        S3BucketName=os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET_NAME'),
        IamRoleArn=os.environ.get('IAM_ROLE_FOR_EXPORT_TASK'),
        KmsKeyId=os.environ.get('KMS_KEY_ID'),
        S3Prefix=os.environ.get('S3_PREFIX'),
    )
    status={
        'ExportTaskIdentifier':export['ExportTaskIdentifier'],
        'S3Bucket':export['S3Bucket'],
        'S3Prefix':export['S3Prefix'],
        'Status':export['Status'],
        'ResponseMetadata':export['ResponseMetadata'], 
    }
    print(status)
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': status
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. But can we export snapshot using cloudformation.

Comment: Nope. If you wish you can Create lambda function using cloudfromation. And vote the answer if you feel it's useful.